# Accessing a value of an attribute of a struct using memory address

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am trying to improve my knowledge using pointers in C++ and I want to access to the value of an attribute of a struct by a memory address. I have this struct defined:

```
#pragma once
typedef struct EXAMPLE_STRUCT{
    uint8_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    float c;
} Example_Struct;
```

I want to get the value of ***a*** usign the memory address (not the name of the attribute):

```
Example_Struct* ptr;
ptr = &(wheather_struct[0]);
```

At this momment, I have in ***ptr*** the memory address value of the first element in the struct. So, I think this is the memory address of ***a*** variable. Then I tried to get the value of this memory address just like:

```
uint8_t value;
value = *ptr;
```

But I have an error on compilation:

> Error C2440: '=' the conversion can not be done from 'Example_Struct' to 'uint8_t'

Could you help me to access ***a*** value using only pointers? (without name reference example_struct->a)

Comment: Cast your pointer to `Example_Struct` to a pointer to `uint8_t`.

Comment: If I change Example_Struct* ptr; to uint8_t *p; I get the same error. I do not know how can I access to the value of uint8_t with the memory addres of the first wheather_struct element :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example to access the first member of the struct.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>

struct example_struct{
    uint8_t a;
    uint16_t b;
    float c;
};

int main()
{
    example_struct a;
    a.a =42;
    uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t*)&a;
    float *fptr = (float *)(((uint8_t *)&a) + offsetof(EXAMPLE_STRUCT, c));

    std::cout << "Hello, " << +(*ptr) << "!\n";
    std::cout << "Hello, " << +(*fptr ) << "!\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Xaqq, I tested it and this example works for me. But If I want  to access to **c** variable using an offset against a name reference. It is possible?

Comment: @Xaqq can you change the identity of the struct with lowercase letters because it looks as a macro or constant.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the first element of the structure as you would access the first element of an array( with `[0]`). Structure elements are accessed only by name.

If you want to get the address of the structure you can do it like this.

```
typedef struct example
{
    int a;
} Example_Struct;
```

Accessing elements.

```
Example_Struct exampleStruct;
exampleStruct.a = 5; // accessing the first element

Example_Struct* structPtr = &exampleStruct; // pointer to the structure
structPtr->a = 10; // accessing the first element

int* intPtr = &(exampleStruct.a); // pointer to the first element of the struct
int* intPtr2 = &(structPtr->a) // also pointer to the first element
```

There is a way to access the first element without using its name but it's not a good practice.

The structure is only a place in memory where you store your data. So casting the pointer to the structure to another type will give you the memory represented as this type.

```
Example_Struct exampleStruct;
int* firstElPtr = (int*)&exampleStruct; //representing the memmory as an int
int firstEl = *((int*)&exampleStruct); //representing and dereferencing the memmory as an int
```

Note that the point of creating a structure is that the elements can be accessed by their names and it is safe and most performant.
If you want to do such things better use an array of `uint8` or you may have issues with memory alignment.

Comment: But I want to access the values of the Example_Struct attributes by memory address, without name reference structPtr->a. Is this possible?

Comment: It is, but you have to type cast it and its not a good practice. These are the ways to access the elements.

Comment: `#pragma once` is telling the compiler to include headers only one time. I believe it has nothing to do with the alignment. There are ways to force the alignment to packed or padded but IMHO it's better to not use these. Let the compiler decide what is optimal for your machine and access the fields with their names. :)

Comment: @JoseJimRin Thank you too. Please accept one of the answers if your problem is solved.